Replaced gas water heater. See spark but gas does not get to pilot tube
Replaced water heater.
pressed pilot knob inwards. On each trigger button press I do see spark, but pilot does not turn on.
Then I removed pilot tube from control panel, kept pilot light pressed. Natural gas detector stick does not register any gas nor I can smell gas.

Removed gas supply to water heater and it registers natural gas and i can smell it.
What could it be:
Low gas pressure?
Defective unit?
Some special instructions I have forgotten for new installation?

It can often take an annoyingly long time to flush out the air and get gas all the way through a small tube. But you're saying you took the tube off the panel and no gas came out from the panel where the tube connects to it?
